# How to access data passed within a function in AnyChartJS?

Tags: javascript, anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm trying to change my Gantt chart tasks bar to rounded corners.

Following this tutorial [here](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/GANTT_Custom_Drawing_01). But this sample doesn't have modifications for progress bars, so I used the method `progress()` to access progress bars and added this:

`tasks.progress().rendering().drawer(drawingFunction)`

I noticed that if I apply the rounded corners, to data with **zero** `progressValue`, it shows the progress bars with **concave** corners, which progress should not be visible at all or at least convex corners **(possible bug)**:

[image]

Now as workaround, I'm thinking to add validation for `progressValue = 0` and move it from there, but then to the question how do I get the value of `progressValue` inside `drawingFunction()`?

```
// a function for drawing custom elements
var drawingFunction = function () {

  // get the shapes of the element
  var shapes = this["shapes"];
  // get the shape to be modified
  var path = shapes["path"];
  // get the bounds of the element
  var bounds = this["predictedBounds"];

  var h = bounds.height;
  var t = bounds.top;
  var l = bounds.left;
  var r = bounds.left + bounds.width;
  var h1 = bounds.top + bounds.height;    
  var h4 = h / 4;
  var h2 = h / 2;

  // draw a rounded rectangle
  path.moveTo(l + h4, h1 - h4)
  path.arcTo(h4, h4, -270, 180)
  path.lineTo(r - h4, t + h4)
  path.arcTo(h4, h4, -90, 180)
  path.lineTo(l + h2, h1 - h4)
  path.close(); 

}
```

What I tried:

- Passing a parameter in the `drawingFunction` and accessing it using:
  `myparameter.item.na.progressValue`. This works but it's kind a dirty hack.
- Tried `this.value`, `this.getValue('progressValue')`, `this.getValue('value')`. But got nothing.

Is there any like global method to access the data anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `drawingFunction()` you can get the required value like this:

```
this.tag.item.get('progressValue')
```

For details, check the [modified sample](https://playground.anychart.com/N8qLXSsr).

There's no bug with the drawing function. You get the bars with concave corners because the bar width is less than 2x corner radius. You have to reduce the radius or somehow handle the situation when the progress value is quite small.

Comment: Hi there! that is what I thought also, when testing the drawing function when I was testing it out, that it is due to some calculations it causes it to concave, the modified sample still is showing concave progress: https://snipboard.io/Cn2GkI.jpg on my end. Also I quick search your answer but I can't find anywhere in the API documentation about `tag` property. Anyway I have already abandoned for now using round corners due to deadlines.

Comment: The API Reference describes only namespaces, classes, function and methods. It doesn't include properties. But we do our best to include everything users may need to the event callback context.